# Visual Studio 2017 enable completion after character is typed in F#

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, f#, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a F# project using Visual Studio 2017.
Before, I've used C# and I'm used to great autocompletion in VS that automatically pops-out and shows me a list of local variables, methods and so on when I press any character.

Unfortunately, in F# I need to force autocompletion to show by pressing `ctrl + space`. It shows automatically when I type `someObject.`, but I need to type entire phrase `someObject` or press `ctrl + space` every time I want VS to complete long variable name for me. It gets pretty annoying as I'm used to similar feature in VS Code, Sublime, and C# in VS and it really speeds up coding.

I wonder if there is any setting / plugin / hack to have such feature when using F# inside Visual Studio?
Is it possible to mock `ctrl + space` when I type any character in code editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't currently supported in the VS 2017 RTW tooling.

This [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/2594) seems to add what you're looking for, and it was merged 3 days ago. There's a property dialog added (shown in the PR) to toggle this behaviour on/off.

For that reason (and plenty of other compelling reasons - the RTW tooling is stable, but it's not without its share of issues) I'd suggest you try the latest [Visual F# Nightly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/) builds.

I've just tried the latest build (as at 18 March), and this works as you describe and is enabled by default.